# Delete iTunes U downloads without removing their reference

Tags: itunes, video, itunes-u

I have many iTunes U videos that take a lot of space on my disk.
I don't really need them on my disk but I would like to keep their reference in my iTunes U library so I can re-download them when needed.

How can I do that?

Comment: I haven't checked this myself, but isn't there a "Downloads" or "Purchased" tab in iTunes U, that you can easily get previous downloads? That is possible with music, apps, etc. so I'm guessing it would work with iTunes U.

Comment: I want to have it in my list with the option "get" as I had it before downloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the videos. Then right-click on the course title and select *Show all available items*. This will restore the complete list of available episodes.

[image]

You can also do this by option-clicking on the disclosure arrow of the course. The arrow needs to be closed before option-clicking in order for this to work.

[image]